# Skydrive embed code not removing vertical scroll bar?

Tags: embed, onedrive, iframe

I'm attempting to add an excel spreadsheet (ROI Calculator) onto our website.

I've come across this fix to use Microsoft's Skydrive app.
http://www.microsoft.com/web/solutions/excel-embed.aspx

So I've followed this and placed my file into Skydrive, shared the folder and exported the embed code through their embed wizard.

But when it displays on my website it's not removing the vertical scroll bar even though the code shows **scrolling="no"**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
The scrollbar appears if you are using the "Entire Workbook" option.

I've managed to get around this by using the 'Select a Range' option instead. Which works for me.